# How to solve context deadline exceeded error when executing a nuclei template?

Tags: templates, yaml

I have made this personal nuclei template to detect if directory listing is enabled on a wordpress site, this template should request the endpoint /wp-content/uploads.and it does a regex match of the string "Index of", if found it should return the result, but so far i'm having this "context deadline exceeded"
Here's the template:
`
id: wordpress-directory-listing

```
info:
  name: /wp-content/uploads - Directory Listing Enabled
  author: winteri3coming
  severity: high
  description: detects if directory listing is enabled at /wp-content/uploads/.
  tags: wordpress

requests:
  - method: GET
    path:
      - "{{BaseURL}}/wp-content/uploads/"
    unsafe: true
    matchers:
      - type: regex
        regex:
          - "[Ii]ndex of"
```

`
i've tried changing the request type to raw and back to basic and it didn't work, what could be the reason and how to fix it, what is wrong with my template, knowing that if i run other templates from the project discovery repo, they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[nuclei documentation unsafe flag](https://nuclei.projectdiscovery.io/template-examples/http-smuggling/) seems like the *unsafe* flag is used to create malformed requests, but if you want other option for a "Directory Listing Enabled" template, it would be:

```
requests:
  - method: GET
    path:
      - "{{BaseURL}}/wp-content/uploads/"
    matchers:
      - type: dsl
        dsl:
          - "status_code_1 == 200 && contains(toupper(body), \"INDEX OF\")"
```

[matchers](https://nuclei.projectdiscovery.io/templating-guide/operators/matchers/) are useful.